# Is there an alternative to timestamp in oracle to show the time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering whether or not there is an alternative to timestamp to display the time as well as date?
I don't really want to use timestamp as it confuses me and I am not sure if I have done it right anyway.

My code can be seen below:

```
--CREATE SCRIPTS
/*put your create scripts here – your script should not commented out*/

-- this is creating a table called Project that contains 3 variables, the primary key being ProjectID
CREATE TABLE Project
(
    Proj_ID integer,
    Proj_Name varchar(10),
    Proj_Start_Date date,
    primary key (Proj_ID)
);
-- this is creating a table called Bug that has 4 variables, BugID being the primary key
CREATE TABLE Bug
(
    Bug_ID integer,
    Bug_Type varchar(20),
    Bug_Desc varchar(20),
    Bug_Time timestamp(4),
    primary key(Bug_ID)
);

-- this is creating a table called Bug_Project with 2 variables; BugID and ProjectID which combine and make a composite key
CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    Bug_ID integer,
    Proj_ID integer,
    primary key(Bug_ID, Proj_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Proj_ID) references  Project (Proj_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Engineer
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Engineer_Name varchar(10),
    Engineer_Type varchar(20),
    primary key (Engineer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Fix_Allocation
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Test_Allocation
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Note
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    Note_author varchar(10),
    Note_contents varchar(20),
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

COMMIT;
--INSERT SCRIPTS
/*put your insert scripts here – your script should not commented out */

INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (00, 'Project 1', DATE '1900-02-14');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (01, 'Project 2', DATE '1950-12-11');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (02, 'Project 3', DATE '1974-07-01');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (03, 'Project 4', DATE '2000-07-22');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (04, 'Project 5', DATE '2012-03-19');

INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (00, 'BugType1', 'Bug Description', timestamp '1997-01-31 09:26:50.12' );
INSERT INTO Bug VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bug VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Bug_Project VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bug_Project VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bug_Project VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES (00, "James", "Tester");
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES (01, "Jeff", "Fixer");
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES (02, "Jacob", "Fixer");
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES (03, "John", "Tester");

INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();

COMMIT;
--SELECT SCRIPT
/*put your select scripts here (with indication of which query is answered) – your script should not commented out

-- Query 1:  List of all the bugs, and their details.
SELECT * FROM Bug;

-- Query 2: List of all bugs, and their notes.

-- Query 3: List of all bugs, with their notes, and the engineers who have written them; sorted by name of engineer.

-- Query 4: List the bugs and how much cumulative time (in hours) they have taken; ordered by time taken.

-- Query 5: The bug that has taken most time to fix, and the projects it is connected to.

COMMIT;
--DROP SCRIPT
/*put your drop scripts here (in the correct order)– your script should not commented out

DROP TABLE Note;
DROP TABLE Test_Allocation;
DROP TABLE Fix_Allocation;
DROP TABLE Engineer;
DROP TABLE Bug_Project;
DROP TABLE Bug;
DROP TABLE Project;

COMMIT;
```

[image: here is the outcome of the first bug insert statement]

here is the outcome of the first bug insert statement, also trying to get rid of all the 0s.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It you remove all stuff not needed to illustrate the problem, you'll probably get better attention. ([mcve].)

Comment: This confuses a lot of newcomers to Oracle. In Oracle the DATE datatype is actually a **datetime**. It holds times to the second i.e. `2019-12-03 09:52:45`

Comment: As you are a newcomer to Oracle can I suggest that you look at a few basic tutorials or something like the Oracle Dev Gym ( https://devgym.oracle.com ).  There are some good presentations on the basics as well as more advanced topics if you choose. Learning is GOOD !

Comment: @BriteSponge ok will do thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DATE` data type stores time and date. Read [Oracle Docs - DATE Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1006006) for more information.